# How to highlight different values in two string objects in angular 7?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7

I have two textareas, when enter data in two textareas . So how to highlight the different keys or values in the data .
Eg: In my html page contains two textareas , after paste the data into two textareas click on difference button , highlight the different strings and count the total difference using in angular7

```js
string1 = " {
                "id": "101",
                "created_time": 1603302391,
                "created_user_id": "58749658",
                "created_user": "siva",
            },
             {
                "id": "102",
                "created_time": 1603302394,
                "created_user_id": "32145678",
                "created_user": "siva",
            }"

string2 = " {
                "id": "111",
                "created_time": 1603382391,
                "created_user_id": "7894569",
                "created_user": "siva",
                "notes":"segrsegeg"
            },
             {
                "id": "102",
                "created_time": 1603302394,
                "created_user_id": "32145678",
                "created_user": "siva",
                "notes":"segrsegeg"
            }"
```

Answer (score 0):

Basicly you must find where is the difference between string and you must add  in your html.
You can use HighligtPipe for it.In .ts file add  tag where is the difference between two words.Then in your html you can use it like

```
{ $implicit: item | highlight: toHighlight : searchWord}

@Pipe({name: 'highlight'})
export class HighlightPipe implements PipeTransform {
 transform(text: any, search: any, searchKeyword?: any): any { 
 const regex = new RegExp(pattern, 'gi');
  const name = text[searchWord].replace(regex, (match) => `<b>${match}</b>`);
  const text2 = {...text};
  // set bold value into searchWord
  text2[searchWord] = name;
  return text2;
 }
}
```